# jquery .hover() for navigation

Tags: jquery

i make navigation function that changes navigation default image to hover image.

default image name is "main.png" and hover image is "main_hover.png"

i know how to extract image name from html src attribute by help of jquery, but i down know how to add additional string between file name "main" and file extension ".png"

my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav").hover(function(){
        var default_button = this.src;
        // here is part where i need help with adding "_hover" to default_image
        $(this).attr('src', default_button) // i know i need this after image is not hovered
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav").hover(function(){
        var default_button = this.src.replace(".jpg","_hover.jpg");
        $(this).attr('src', default_button) 
    });
});
```

Comment: i needed to add few lines, but thx for help! .replace() dose the job! :)

Answer (score 5):

May be you should not do this via jQuery, why not use the css way?

```
.nav {
 background: url(/path/to/main.png)
}

.nav:hover {
  background: url(/path/to/main_hover.png)
}
```

Comment: +1 Absolutely this.  No reason to use javascript for something that CSS can handle just fine.

Comment: i'd like to suggest putting the hover and regular state in one image and use background-position on hover if possible.

Comment: @MatthewGrima Spriting would indeed be the best way to do this

Comment: i need jQuery because if I do it your way then i need to make CSS rule to each button (on one site i may have 1 button on other 20 buttons)
so i thought about jQuery "ultimate" function for all buttons.

Comment: @AinārsSprosts I don't see your point, with jQuery you're also adding behaviour to one class, and with the css solution the css stated above would do the same, but I do not know your css nor your DOM.